# Using yii relations to get data across different models

Tags: php, yii

I'm still new to Yii, but I'm trying to use relations() to join two tables and get all data from both table on each row pulled.

```
tables:
TABLE Artist KEYS(artist_Id, firstName, lastName)
TABLE Album KEYS(album_Id, title, artist_Id, genre)

// Album
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'artist' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Artist', 'artist_Id'),
        'track' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Track', 'track_Id')
    );
}

// Artist
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'album' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Album', 'album_id')
    );
}

// logic for getting information
$dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Album');
foreach($dataProvider->getData() as $key){
    echo  '<br>' . $key->artist_Id;  // does work
    echo  '<br>' . $key->firstName; // doesn't work
}
```

With this code, I can get and display the correct artist_Id for the album. However, I want to display the artist firstName and lastName with the artist_Id.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to change my `$dataProvider` variable and how I was trying to access in the view index.php

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Album');
```

-to-

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Album', array('criteria' => array('with' => array('artist'))));
```

and changing view index.php to one of the two:

```
'name' => 'artist.lastName',
```

or

```
'value' => '$data->artist->firstName'
```